# Bed temperature is changing randomly

Tags: heated-bed, temperature

While printing the bed temperature is changing like this. If the print time is below 30 minutes, printers stops after print two layers. But longer then 30 minutes, finishing job. I changed bed thermistor but problem still going. There was no problem until upload the Marlin Bugfix 2.0 . I connected BL TOUCH on my printer and its working correctly. I didn't change any PID or temperature settings on Marlin Bugfix 2.0
2-hour print has just been successfully completed. But when i print something for 10 minutes the printer stops working

Printer : My own design COREXY
Firmware : Marlin Bugfix 2.0
Motherboard : MKS Base V1.6
Slicer : Prusa Slicer

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the config files to make sure that the correct motherboard has been selected? The thread [bugfix 2.0.x: Occasional hotend temperature glitch when printing](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/11323) gives me the impression that different ADCs in the processor need different settings to get reliable readings.

Comment: Hello Demir, you need to read what solves the fixes you are adding with the bugfix, if the bugfix solves a problem you had try to verify installing other bugfix version. If you added the bugfix just to be up to date, I recommend remove the bugfix. Seen the LCD temp, seems to be a wire from sensor is not connected (broken internally).